# Prove that $V$ is the direct sum of $W_1$ and $W_2$ if and only if each vector in $V$ can be uniquely written as $x_1 + x_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $W_1$ and $W_2$ be subspaces of a vector space $V$. Prove that $V$ is the direct sum of $W_1$ and $W_2$ if and only if each vector in $V$ can be uniquely written as  $x_1 + x_2$, where $x_1 \in W_1$ and $x_2 \in W_2$

My attempt:

Proving $P \implies Q$:

Let $v \in V$, such that $v = a_1 + a_2$ and $v = b_1 + b_2$ whenever $a_1, b_1 \in W_1, a_2, b_2 \in W_2$

$\therefore a_1 + a_2 = b_1 + b_2$

$\therefore a_1 - b_1 = b_2 - a_2$    Since $W_1$ and $W_2$ are subspaces $a_1 - b_1 $ is in $W_1$.  Similarly $b_2 - a_2$ is in $W_2$.

But $W_1 \cap W_2 = \{0\}  \implies  a_1 = b_1$ and $a_2 = b_2$. Hence uniqueness is proved.

But I am having trouble proving the part. $Q \implies P$ i.e.   if each vector in $V$ can be uniquely written as  $x_1 + x_2$, where $x_1 \in W_1$ and $x_2 \in W_2$, then $V$ is the direct sum of $W_1$ and $W_2$

Comment: Assuming $Q$, you already have $V = W_1 + W_2$. So it remains to show that $W_1\cap W_2= 0$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: @thedilated How can you say that $V = W_1 + W_2$?. It is not proven yet.

Comment: It is by definition isn't it? Every vector $v\in V$ can be written as an sum $w_1+ w_2$ where $w_i \in W_i$ for $i=1,2$. That means $V= W_1+W_2$.

Comment: Oh, got it. But still unable to proceed.

Comment: If you have a vector $w \in W_1 \cap W_2 \subset V$, what can you say about $w$?